# Root Remove Remote % host. My SQL

Tags: mysql

So i accidentally made it so root can be accessed anywhere remotely how do i revoke the % privilege. Using mysql.

```
+-----------+
| host      |
+-----------+
| %         |
| 127.0.0.1 |
| ::1       |
| localhost |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did it with a `GRANT`, run the corresponding `REVOKE`.

Or you could run this.  (Suggest you dump `mysql.user` first, just in case.)

```
DELETE FROM mysql.user
    WHERE user = 'root'
      AND host = '%';
```